# How to get value of 'this' inputbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web application where the user clicks on a div, that is holding a input text box with predefined text in it. When the user clicks on the div the code is then printed in a separate text box. I am trying to write a function that grabs the value of the the clicked on div's text input. I have it working by clicking on the input box itself by using     `$(this).val();` but I want to click on the div and then it essentially gets the value of `(this)('input[type=text].provided_code').val();`

is there a way to say the text input inside this div? There are like 20 div's on the page with 20 inputs in each div, and each have the same class name etc.

Comment: Please show us some html, if only to stop people incorrectly answering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can specify the selector context:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function

Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

So you code could look like this:

```
$('input[type=text].provided_code', this).val()
```

Performance:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/38

Comment: This seems to work the best in my situation. Thanks for the quick and great response. I was using `(this)('input[type=text].provided_code')` which was obviously throwing an error.

Comment: Just as a side note, `$(this).find('input[type=text].provided_code')` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do:

```
$(this).find("input[type='text']").val();
```

Assuming that there is one input of type text inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(this)('input[type=text].provided_code').val();`

you should use a correct jQuery with the find function.

`$(this).find('input[type="text"].provided_code'].val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` - Although, you cannot target a specific input on click of your div unless that input has a unique class or id.

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
  var value = $(this).find('input[type=text].provided_code').val();
})
```